# Circleci 2.0 Build on Dockerfile

Tags: docker, circleci

I have a Node.JS application that I'd like to build and test using CircleCI and Amazon ECR. The documentation is not clear on how to build an image from a Dockerfile in a repository. I've looked here: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/ and here https://circleci.com/blog/multi-stage-docker-builds/ but it's not clear what I put under the executor. Here's what I've got so far:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
    steps:
        - checkout
        - setup_remote_docker:
            version: 17.05.0-ce
        # build the image
        - run: docker build -t $ECR_REPO:0.1 .
```

CircleCI fails with the following error:

```
* The job has no executor type specified. The job should have one of the following keys specified: "machine", "docker", "macos"
```

The base image is take from the Dockerfile. I'm using CircleCI's built in AWS Integration so I don't think I need to add aws_auth. What do I need to put under the executor to get this running?

Answer (score 3):

Build this with a Docker-in-Docker config:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: /app
    docker:
      - image: docker:17.05.0-ce-git
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          name: Install dependencies
          command: |
            apk add --no-cache \
              py-pip=9.0.0-r1 gcc \
              libffi-dev python-dev \
              linux-headers \
              musl-dev \
              libressl-dev \
              make
            pip install \
              docker-compose==1.12.0 \
              awscli==1.11.76 \
              ansible==2.4.2.0
      - run:
          name: Save Vault Password to File
          command: echo $ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASS > .vault-pass.txt
      - run:
          name: Decrypt .env
          command: |
            ansible-vault decrypt .circleci/envs --vault-password-file .vault-pass.txt
      - run:
          name: Move .env
          command: rm -f .env && mv .circleci/envs .env
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-{{ .Branch }}
          paths:
            - /caches/app.tar
      - run:
          name: Load Docker image layer cache
          command: |
            set +o pipefail
            docker load -i /caches/app.tar | true
      - run:
          name: Build application Docker image
          command: |
            docker build --cache-from=app -t app .
      - run:
          name: Save Docker image layer cache
          command: |
            mkdir -p /caches
            docker save -o /caches/app.tar app
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
          paths:
            - /caches/app.tar
      - deploy:
          name: Push application Docker image
          command: |
            if [ "${CIRCLE_BRANCH}" == "master" ]; then
              login="$(aws ecr get-login --region $ECR_REGION)"
              ${login}
              docker tag app "${ECR_ENDPOINT}:${CIRCLE_SHA1}"
              docker push "${ECR_ENDPOINT}:${CIRCLE_SHA1}"
            fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a Docker image for your build to run in in the first place. This should work:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: docker:stable-git
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker:
          version: 17.05.0-ce
      # build the image
      - run: docker build -t $ECR_REPO:0.1 .
```

Comment: insert dancing emogi!!  Thank you . .